# Pandas from Django .last() query

Tags: django, pandas

I can not create a dataframe when using only a single row - in this case using the .last() record for all the users.

I am trying to get the very last row information.

```
for i in a:

    qs = Cash.objects.filter ( id = i.id ).order_by ( 'month' ).last()

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records ( qs )
```

or something like

```
    df = read_frame ( qs )
```

I get the following error:

```
object of type 'Cash' has no len()
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [slicing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) to limit queryset with one record:

```
qs = Cash.objects.filter ( id = i.id ).order_by ( '-month' )[:1]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records ( qs )
```

Note that negative indexing is not supported.

Comment: how would I handle a query like this?   qs = Cash.objects.filter ( acct = i.id ).aggregate(Max('month'), Min('month'), Avg('value'))

Comment: @diogenes try to use `from_dict` like this: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(qs)`. Since `aggregate` return dict, it should work.